# Archive & autoarchive not working

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, archiving

I'm using Outlook 2010 w/ Exchange, and one of my folders has AutoArchive setup on it:

> Archive this folder using these settings: Clean out items older than 2 weeks
>
> Move old items to default archive folder

I went to `File->Cleanup Tools->Archive...->selected this folder->OK` and it said "Archiving at the bottom.

I also went to `File->Cleanup Tools->Mailbox Cleanup->AutoArchive` and archiving ran.

But in the folder, all the messages are still there and haven't been archived. There are emails dating back to Dec 2012.

Why is archiving not working? Other folders are fine, and I have tried re-opening Outlook.

Comment: Did you select the "Archive emails older than ..." and select the date you want?  You know you can just drop and drag the emails you want to archive right?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I did, that's in my first quote box. I know I can drag, but still concerned why a feature in Outlook isn't working.